# HTML5 video, how are the video data sent to the browser?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using C++ to implement an HTML5 live video server.

The source stream is read from a camera device (H264) and this is done. I can also save the source (h264 codec) video into a file.

I want to implement an HTML5 live server. But I cannot find any protocol description for this. For simplicity, I just want to implement auto-play (no-pause no stop until close the browser).

How does the HTML protocol work? The browser will send me a request for a "fake" file isn't it? So I can then start sending live video information continuously like saving to a file? Is there anything I can know about this file transferring protocol in HTML? Is there anything special for HTML5 video comparing to a normal file?

I know VLC can do this (some searches from stackoverflow) but my application is a little special and needs more functions than VLC can support. And my application is not a generic video server, I just need to support a specific task, so it's not hard to implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detail will be different depending on whether you have a single video stream or multiple streams (to allow switching between different size streams according to network conditions - i.e. adaptive bit rate streaming), but in general the video player in the browser, or the HTML5/Javascript video player, will request 'chunks' of video from the server one after the other.

You can see this if you take a look at the 'network' section of the browser console when playing a video - you should see multiple requests from the browser to the server for the video chunks (and for audio chunks if the audio is a separate stream). See below for an example (Chrome playing a YouTube video):

[image]

Depending on the actual protocol being used, how the browser/player decides what to request and how it builds the request will be slightly different. For example one of the simplest ways is that the server supports 'Range Requests' or 'Byte Serving' in the HTTP request - this allows the server respond with just a portion of the file specified by the range in a given HTTP request.

More complex adaptive bit rate streaming protocols, such as HLS, SmoothStreaming, HDS and DASH, generally have the concept of some sort of extra data about the video and audio streams available which the player will use to choose a stream and to request a chunk - for example a DASH manifest or 'mpd' file which contains info on the streams, timing, DRM if appropriate etc. They may even include mechanisms to allow 'old' chunks of a live stream by requested for someone who is late starting viewing the event. Regardless, the principles are still the same - the video player sends multiple separate requests for chunks of video and/or audio, and assembles the chunks locally to play them back in the browser.

It might be easiest to look at one of the open source video streaming servers to see if you can adapt it, even if your requirements are a bit different.